# Reading a tfrecord: DecodeError: Error parsing message

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am using colab to run a [tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/ranking/blob/master/tensorflow_ranking/examples/handling_sparse_features.ipynb) on tensorflow ranking. It uses wget to fetch the tfrecord:

```
!wget -O "/tmp/train.tfrecords" "http://ciir.cs.umass.edu/downloads/Antique/tf-ranking/ELWC/train.tfrecords"
```

I am using this code to try to look at the structure of the tfrecord:

```
for example in tf.compat.v1.python_io.tf_record_iterator("/tmp/train.tfrecords"):
    print(tf.train.Example.FromString(example))
    break
```

And I am getting:

```
DecodeError: Error parsing message
```

How to generally look at the structure of tfrecords instead?

A second question: Where to find documentation on classes like `tf.train.Example`? I just find this [empty page](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The insight of the problem is that the records are serialized using another schema: the `ExampleListWithContext` Schema, instead of the basic `tf.train.Example` schema. Updating the right deserialization solves the problem.

```
filenames = ['/tmp/train.tfrecords']
raw_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
for e in raw_dataset.take(1):
    ELWC = input_pb2.ExampleListWithContext()
    v = ELWC.FromString(e.numpy())
    print(v.context)
    for e in v.examples:
        print(e)
```

outputs:

```
features {
  feature {
    key: "query"
    value {
      bytes_list {
        value: "why do ..."
      }
    }
  }
  feature {
    key: "query_bert_encoder_outputs"
    value {
      float_list {
...
}}
```